# Firebase admin not working with jest, logging a import error

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, jestjs

I am trying to initialize the firebase admin, but my credentials are fetched from the s3, while most of my test cases pass, without any issue but jest gives the following error:

I believe this is the console log in the `catch(e)`

```
Attempted to log "FirebaseAppError: Failed to parse private key: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'privateKeyFromPem')
```

even though when I console log the response from s3 it is a valid response and the code actually is working.

The following code is executed as soon as the node-js server is started:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const {S3_FOLDERS, ENVIRONMENTS} = require('../constants');
const s3 = require('./s3.init');

(async function initializeFirebase() {
  try {
    await process.nextTick(() => { });
    let config = await s3.getObject({
      Bucket: `http://private-dummy-bucket-url`,
      Key: `firebase-config.json`,
    }).promise();

    config = JSON.parse(config.Body?.toString());

    admin.initializeApp({
      credential: admin.credential.cert(config),
      databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
})();
```

I have 22 tests in 6 test suites. All of them pass but some tests log the error mentioned above. The `timezone.routes.spec` which is mentioned in the error does use s3 service to get and upload objects but never requires firebase.

```
Test Suites: 6 passed, 6 total
Tests:       22 passed, 22 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.011 s, estimated 7 s
Ran all test suites.

ReferenceError: You are trying to `import` a file after the Jest environment has been torn down. From tests/timezone.routes.spec.js.

      12 |     config = JSON.parse(config.Body?.toString());
      13 |     admin.initializeApp({
    > 14 |       credential: admin.credential.cert(config),
         |                                    ^
      15 |       databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
      16 |     });
      17 |   } catch (e) {

      at new ServiceAccount (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:137:21)
      at new ServiceAccountCredential (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential-internal.js:68:15)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.cert (node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/credential/credential.js:34:54)
      at cert (initializers/firebase.init.js:14:36)
```